# I can no longer create a server listening on port 64951 or 64952 under Windows 10

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I can no longer create a server listening on port 64951 or 64952 under Windows 10.

I got an exception on my C# program when I tried to bind to 0.0.0.0:64951.

Same on a C++/Qt program, the error is : 'the address is protected'.

In Tcpview I didn't find a process using these ports for listening on  0.0.0.0:64951 or  0.0.0.0:64952

what could be the explanation for this problem ?

Update :

```
C:\Users\>netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

 

Protocole tcp Plages d'exclusion de ports

 

Port de début    Port de fin
-------------    -----------
      5357        5357
     49152       49251
     49252       49351
     50000       50059     *
     64916       65015
     65206       65305
     65306       65405
     65406       65505

 

* - Exclusions de ports administrés.
```

Comment: It is clear from the sreenshot that ports `64951` and `64952` are in the excluded range `64916..65015`, they are being "protected" by Windows, that is why you can't use them in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue :

```
net stop winnat

net start winnat
```

When you run the command `netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` You should have something like :

```
Protocole tcp Plages d'exclusion de ports

Port de début    Port de fin
-------------    -----------
      5357        5357
     50000       50059     *

* - Exclusions de ports administrés.
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP's concern about WHY this is happening.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's true, I don't know why these ports have been blocked by Windows 10. the solution I have posted was given to me by a colleague.